# Adding string user input into an array list based on how many iterations

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, iteration

I am working on a Java project and I have my Super class with private attributes. I use the accessors and mutators I inherited from my superclass inside Main to set and get these attributes. I am creating a for loop to iterate through the inputs based on the INT number of the user. I am stuck on how do I take my user inputs of the Name and add it to an ArrayList inside the loop, so when it is done I should have X number of names.

```
        Scanner  input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> animalList = new ArrayList<String>();
        //local variables
        char     choice;
        int      choice2;
        String   mInputN;
        String   mInputT;
        String   mInputG;
        int      mInputA;
        double   mInputW;
        String   mInputD;

        //user input if else statement for Y or N
        System.out.println("Would you like to add an animal? Y or N ");
        choice = input.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
        if (choice == 'Y')  {

            System.out.println("How many animals would you like to add?");
            choice2 = input.nextInt();

            for (i = 0; i < choice2; ++i)  {
                System.out.println("Enter new animal name: ");
                mInputN = input.next();

                System.out.println("Enter type of animal: ");
                mInputT = input.next();

                System.out.println("Enter gender of animal: ");
                mInputG = input.next();

                System.out.println("Enter age of animal: ");
                mInputA = input.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Enter weight of animal: ");
                mInputW = input.nextDouble();

                System.out.println("Date acquired (DD/MM/YYYY");
                mInputD = input.next();

                RescueAnimal animal[i] = new RescueAnimal();
                animal[i].setName(mInputN);
                animal[i].setType(mInputT);
                animal[i].setGender(mInputG);
                animal[i].setAge(mInputA);
                animal[i].setWeight(mInputW);
                animal[i].setAcquisitionDate(mInputD);

                animalList.add(mInputN);

                System.out.println(animal[i].getName() + ", Age: " + animal[i].getAge() + ", Gender: " + animal[i].getGender());
                System.out.print("Type: " + animal[i].getType() + ", ");
                System.out.print("Weight: " + animal[i].getWeight() + ", ");
                System.out.println("Acquisition Date: " + animal[i].getAcquisitionDate());
                System.out.println();

                System.out.println(animalList);
            }
```

Comment: have you tried ```System.out.println(animalList);``` outside of the for loop?

Comment: You want to add _just_ the names to `AnimalList`?  You've already got code that does that (`animalList.add(mInputn);`).

Comment: @BookOfZeus yep, that was it, thank you for your help, I was up all day working on it by the end of the day my brain was missing the most crucial piece.

Answer (score 0):

Well if your just going to do `System.out.println(animalList);` then you are just going to get a memory location and not the actaual things inside this list; so what I personally do is after the user inputs and completes the loop write this code out side the first for loop. It is a for each loop: (delete the last `System.out.println();`)

```
for(String i : animalList){
System.out.println(i);
}
```

Or you could also do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < animalList.length; i++){
System.out.println(animalList[i]);
}
```

And also after your finish printing out the animal's info do:

```
 System.out.println("Acquisition Date: " + animal[i].getAcquisitionDate() + "\n);
```

Instead of:

```
System.out.println("Acquisition Date: " + animal[i].getAcquisitionDate());
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

First the code. Explanations after the code.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RescueAnimal {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String gender;
    private int age;
    private double weight;
    private String acquisitionDate;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public String getAcquisitionDate() {
        return acquisitionDate;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public void setAcquisitionDate(String acquisitionDate) {
        this.acquisitionDate = acquisitionDate;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<RescueAnimal> animalList = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Would you like to add an animal? Y or N ");
        char choice = input.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
        if (choice == 'Y')  {
            System.out.println("How many animals would you like to add?");
            int choice2 = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < choice2; ++i)  {
                System.out.println("Enter new animal name: ");
                String mInputN = input.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter type of animal: ");
                String mInputT = input.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter gender of animal: ");
                String mInputG = input.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter age of animal: ");
                int mInputA = input.nextInt();
                input.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter weight of animal: ");
                double mInputW = input.nextDouble();
                input.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Date acquired (DD/MM/YYYY");
                String mInputD = input.nextLine();

                RescueAnimal animal = new RescueAnimal();
                animal.setName(mInputN);
                animal.setType(mInputT);
                animal.setGender(mInputG);
                animal.setAge(mInputA);
                animal.setWeight(mInputW);
                animal.setAcquisitionDate(mInputD);

                animalList.add(animal);

                System.out.println(animal.getName() + ", Age: " + animal.getAge() + ", Gender: " + animal.getGender());
                System.out.print("Type: " + animal.getType() + ", ");
                System.out.print("Weight: " + animal.getWeight() + ", ");
                System.out.println("Acquisition Date: " + animal.getAcquisitionDate());
                System.out.println();

                System.out.println(animalList.size());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You want to create a list of `RescueAnimal` and not a list of `String`.
You have not declared any arrays so you don't need `[i]`. An `ArrayList` is not an array.
All you want to do is create an instance of `RescueAnimal` from the details entered by the user and then add that `RescueAnimal` instance to your list.